# Inactive versus frozen orbitals in CASSCF

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, software

Does it make any difference if I use the `frozen` keyword instead of the `inactive` keyword in MOLCAS CASSCF calculations?

Comment: read [here](http://www.molcas.org/documentation/manual/node100.html), chapter 8.33.0.1